# Problems with Yii2 creation Rules

Tags: yii2

I have a Yii2 with Yii2 admin, user andAdminLTE installed. My problem is I don't know how to create rules, actually I don't know how to define the Class Name. Where "Classes" should be defined? How can I see which Classes do I have or add Classes?

[image]

Thanks a lot,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with Yii2 Rules creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652290/problems-with-yii2-rules-creation)

Answer (score 0):

The class that you'll enter should be the child class of `yii\rbac\Rule`. So, in order to make a rule you need to provide the `namespace` of this child class. Suppose, if the name of the child class is `TestRule` and the `namespace` of this class is `app\test`. Then you must write the class name as `app\test\TestRule`.

And your `TestRule` class must look like

```
namespace app\test;

class TestRule extends yii\rbac\Rule{
...
}
```